# How to horizontally center navbar content in Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I recently began messing around with Tailwind & I decided that the first component would be a basic navbar with the following qualities.

- Logo which should sit ***horizontally center*** of the screen
- Navigation links on either side of the logo

Here's a simplified version of my attempt:

```
    <nav class=" flex fixed w-screen justify-center items-center text-center">
      <!-- Left Navigation -->
      <div>
        <a class="mx-2">LINK ONE</a>
        <a class="mx-2">LINK TWO</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Logo -->
      <div class="mx-12">L</div>
      <!-- Right Navigation -->
      <div>
        <a class="mx-2">LINK THREEE</a>
        <a class="mx-2">LINK FOOOUR</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

My original approach was to have a flexbox container (nav) that would hold three divs, one for each section of the navbar, and to then use the justify-center class (`justify-content: center;`) to position the logo directly in the center of the screen, with the left & right navigation links falling on either side.

Once I tried this, I quickly found out that the `justify-center` class helped me position all of the divs and their content to the center of the screen along the container's axis. However, I didn't consider that the text on the right side of the logo is longer and thus pushes the logo slightly off-center to the left, relative to the center of the screen.

So, my question is, how can I center the logo horizontally - *dead center* - on the screen & not have the left or right navigation links push the logo off-center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it with the following:

```html
<nav class="flex fixed w-screen">
    <!-- Left Navigation -->
    <div class="flex-1 flex justify-center mr-auto">
        <a class="mx-2">LINK ONE</a>
        <a class="mx-2">LINK TWO</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Logo -->
    <div class="mx-12">L</div>
    <!-- Right Navigation -->
    <div class="flex-1 flex justify-center ml-auto">
        <a class="mx-2">LINK THREEE</a>
        <a class="mx-2">LINK FOOOUR</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Giving each flex item `flex-1` allows each item to grow (or shrink) while ignoring its initial size. This distributes the space equally between the items. Making each of the items a center justified item and using `mr-auto` and `ml-auto` respectively distributes the free space evenly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please ellaborate on how and why this works, for future reference?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have a follow up question.

I tried to limit the size of the navbar itself with the class: max-w-xl & it makes the entire navbar float to the left side. Any idea why?

Comment: So you want to limit the width and still have the navbar remain centered?

Comment: I believe this is the issue OP is talking about: https://play.tailwindcss.com/6jw9SuW7Dq

This is due to the use of the `fixed`class. You can limit the maximum width of the elements within the nav bar, by wrapping the content in another `div` and limiting its size, like this: https://play.tailwindcss.com/VzVv3uFke8

Comment: @ptts Is correct. That was the issue I was having. I managed to fix it just as ptts came in with the solution. Thanks to you both. :)